# How to make a bold sparkline in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-sparkline

Is it possible to thicken the line graph shown when using the formula `=SPARKLINE(L4:L)`?

Comment: Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is parameter `linewidth`.
Example : `=SPARKLINE(L4:L;{"linewidth"\3})`

---

Reminder on how to construct a `=sparkline` :

```
=SPARKLINE("range",{"charttype"\"line","xmin"\0,"ymin"\0,"color"\"orange","empty"\"ignore","linewidth"\6})
```

---

[More on sparkline here.](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/sparkline-line-chart-formula-options/)